# /dev/urandom error in chronyd

Tags: pi-1

I have Crux ARM version 3.2 installed. When I try to start chrony daemon (`/etc/rc.d/chronyd start`) I get a weird error message:

> Can't open /dev/urandom : Permission denied

Some facts:

- I'm doing this from root account.
- The root user and usergroup have permissions to access chronyd.
- I have access to /dev/urandom (tried `dd if=/dev/urandom bs=128
  count=1`).
- I have chrony correctly installed (uninstalled and reinstalled it
  several times to check; I do have runscripts activated in prt-get).

Does anyone have any suggestions to solve the problem?

Comment: What operating system and what version of it are you running? (Check with `uname -a`)

Comment: I'm running Crux ARM version 3.2, as for the kernel I'll have to check, don't remember.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the kernel version is 4.4.19-1

Comment: Hello, did you happen to solve this issue? A project I'm helping on appears to have hit a similar issue.